# Are emoji the same across all devices?

Tags: android, emoji, android-fonts

I quite don't understand, on android kitkat (on a samsung device) and android lolippop (on samsung device) the warning symbol (on the same font, Roboto-Regular) is draw like :

[image]

But on marshmallow (on alcatel pixi 4 device) then is draw in black and white like :

[image]

Are the design of the emoji is depending of the Android version or depending of the device model/manufacturer ?

most important, how can i keep the design of the emoji the same across all android versions / device ?